# Casting a variable to write CSS

Tags: php, css, casting

So, I'm making a table, and I want to use a 4-color scheme selected at random from a group of 10 schemes.

Here's my CSS/PHP:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/css');

 // 0   grey
$color00 = '#959595';       //light grey
$color10 = '#616161';       //medium grey
$color20 = '#414141';       //dark grey
$color30 = '#dfdfdf';       //white grey
//  1   pink 
$color01 = '#e45494';       //light pink
$color11 = '#d70060';       //medium pink
$color21 = '#900040';       //dark pink
$color31 = '#f7ccdf';       //white pink
//  2   red 
$color02 = '#ee576f';       //light red
$color12 = '#e50428';       //medium red
$color22 = '#9a031b';       //dark red
$color32 = '#facdd4';       //white red
//  3   orange 
//(etc, up to 09-39)

$seed   =   rand(0,9);

$lightcolor = "color0".$seed;
$medcolor   = "color1".$seed;
$darkcolor  = "color2".$seed;
$whitecolor = "color3".$seed;

?>


#wttbl{
border:0;
border-collapse:collapse;
cellpadding:3;
width:500px;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:9px;
}

#wttbl td, #wttbl th{
padding: 4px;   
}

#wttbl #header{
background:<?="$lightcolor"?>;  
}

#wttbl td{
text-align:right;
color:#414141;
}

#wttbl .odd{
background:<?="$color33"?>;
}

#wttbl .even{

}

#wttbl tr:hover{
background:<?="$color03"?>;
} 

#wttbl td:hover{
background:<?="$color23"?>;
color:white;     
}
```

The problem is that, hardcoding things like

```
#wttbl .odd{ background:<?="$color33"?>; }
```

seem to work, and echo the proper css color into my code, while things like

```
#wttbl #header{ background:<?="$lightcolor"?>; }
```

echo "color03" into the tag.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You're missing arrays... also using `<?= $something ?>` instead of the equivalent but much less efficient and clear `<?= "$something" ?>`... also, the entire idea of using PHP to generate randomly-colored CSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose a string inside `{}` to reference a variable by the string that makes up its name:

```
$lightcolor = ${"color0".$seed};
$medcolor   = ${"color1".$seed};
$darkcolor  = ${"color2".$seed};
$whitecolor = ${"color3".$seed};

echo $lightcolor;
// #959595
```

This does not seem like the best method, however.  It would be more appropriate to store them in arrays.  Building variable names (called [variable variables in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)) tend to become difficult to debug, especially in the global namespace.  It becomes hard to keep track of what variables have been defined, or how many have been defined.

Comment: variable variables are a terrible idea

Comment: I actually went with `background:<?="${$lightcolor}"?>;` but this works, as well.  I specifically didn't want to use arrays, so this is perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: "I specifically didn't want to use arrays" --- out of curiosity, why?!

Comment: @zerkms forcing myself to do it a different way.  it's just a personal project, and i'm trying to learn around things i know.  this may not be the BEST way, but it's another odd-shaped tool in my bag now.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use arrays:

```
$color = array(
    array('#959595', '#616161', ...),
    array('#e45494', '#d70060', ...)
);

$lightcolor = $color[$seed][0];
```

And no, variable variables is never a good idea, even though there will be several answers mentioning them.

Comment: Agreed; variable-variables are not as intuitive in debugging, and add an extra degree of complexity to the problem when an array would be far simpler.

Comment: And +1 for @zerkms for the correct answer, though not accepted.

Comment: @Michael: `I specifically didn't want to use arrays` - especially this makes me cry. But as long as we gave a *correct* answer - we don't care, right? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms it's not that i don't want to EVER use arrays.  I just didn't here, because I already knew how to do it that way.  The point of this project was to teach myself different ways to do things.  Sorry.